# Jooq custom type with MockResult throwing DataTypeException

Tags: java, sql, groovy, jooq

Getting an error when trying to set up a unit test using Jooq mocking with custom types (Joda Time). I have registered a converter during code generation. It almost looks like Jooq can't find / doesn't see the converter and is trying to fall back on `ConvertAll`, which doesn't work.

Querying the mock result throws the exception (below).

Converter:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.jooq.Converter;

public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter<Timestamp, DateTime> {
    @Override
    public DateTime from(Timestamp databaseObject) {
        return new DateTime(databaseObject.getTime()).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    }

    @Override
    public Timestamp to(DateTime userObject) {
        return new Timestamp(userObject.getMillis());
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Timestamp> fromType() {
        return Timestamp.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DateTime> toType() {
        return DateTime.class;
    }
}
```

The class is generated successfully:

```
/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ
 */
package redacted.generated.jooq.tables;

/**
 * This class is generated by jOOQ.
 */
@javax.annotation.Generated(value    = {"http://www.jooq.org", "3.0.0"},
                            comments = "This class is generated by jOOQ")
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings({ "all", "unchecked" })
public class Bug extends org.jooq.impl.TableImpl<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1992533553;

    /**
     * The singleton instance of <code>public.bug</code>
     */
    public static final redacted.generated.jooq.tables.Bug BUG = new redacted.generated.jooq.tables.Bug();

    /**
     * The class holding records for this type
     */
    @Override
    public java.lang.Class<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord> getRecordType() {
        return redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord.class;
    }

    /**
     * The column <code>public.bug.testdate</code>. 
     */
    public final org.jooq.TableField<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord, org.joda.time.DateTime> TESTDATE = createField("testdate", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.TIMESTAMP.asConvertedDataType(new name.benjaminAbbitt.jooqJodaTime.DateTimeConverter()), this);

    /**
     * The column <code>public.bug.id</code>. 
     */
    public final org.jooq.TableField<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord, java.lang.Integer> ID = createField("id", org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.INTEGER, this);

    /**
     * Create a <code>public.bug</code> table reference
     */
    public Bug() {
        super("bug", redacted.generated.jooq.Public.PUBLIC);
    }

    /**
     * Create an aliased <code>public.bug</code> table reference
     */
    public Bug(java.lang.String alias) {
        super(alias, redacted.generated.jooq.Public.PUBLIC, redacted.generated.jooq.tables.Bug.BUG);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public org.jooq.Identity<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord, java.lang.Integer> getIdentity() {
        return redacted.generated.jooq.Keys.IDENTITY_BUG;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public java.util.List<org.jooq.UniqueKey<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord>> getKeys() {
        return java.util.Arrays.<org.jooq.UniqueKey<redacted.generated.jooq.tables.records.BugRecord>>asList(redacted.generated.jooq.Keys.BUG_ID_KEY);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public redacted.generated.jooq.tables.Bug as(java.lang.String alias) {
        return new redacted.generated.jooq.tables.Bug(alias);
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
org.jooq.exception.DataTypeException: Cannot convert from 2014-03-05T17:57:24.668Z (class org.joda.time.DateTime) to class java.sql.Timestamp
at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.fail(Convert.java:809)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert$ConvertAll.from(Convert.java:747)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert0(Convert.java:296)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:288)
at org.jooq.tools.Convert.convert(Convert.java:349)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.getValue(AbstractRecord.java:219)
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.MockResultSet.getValue(MockResultSet.java:383)
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.MockResultSet.getTimestamp(MockResultSet.java:566)
at org.jooq.impl.Utils.getTimestamp(Utils.java:2195)
at org.jooq.impl.Utils.getFromResultSet(Utils.java:1952)
at org.jooq.impl.Utils.getFromResultSet(Utils.java:1881)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.setValue(CursorImpl.java:1464)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1447)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator$CursorRecordInitialiser.operate(CursorImpl.java:1439)
at org.jooq.impl.RecordDelegate.operate(RecordDelegate.java:119)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.fetchOne(CursorImpl.java:1412)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.next(CursorImpl.java:1389)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl$CursorIterator.next(CursorImpl.java:1353)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:202)
at org.jooq.impl.CursorImpl.fetch(CursorImpl.java:176)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:321)
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:324)
at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:1034)
at org.jooq.ResultQuery$fetch.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
at redacted.bug.BugTest.getTest(BugTest.groovy:47)
```

BugTest.groovy:

```
public class BugTest {
    @Test
    public void getTest() {

        DSLContext testContext = setupDSL(new MockDataProvider() {
            @Override
            public MockResult[] execute(MockExecuteContext ctx) throws SQLException {
                DSLContext create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
                def result = create.newResult(BUG)

                result.add(create.newRecord(BUG, [id: 0, testdate: new DateTime()]))

                [new MockResult(result.size(), result)]
            }
        })

        testContext.select().from(BUG).fetch()  //this line fails
    }

    private DSLContext setupDSL(MockDataProvider provider) {
        MockConnection connection = new MockConnection(provider)
        return DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's curious. It looks like a bug indeed. Will get back to you...

Comment: I've registered [#3114](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3114) to track this issue, but I cannot reproduce it right away. Here's the test case I'm using: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/commit/ce8ad8d9305182a35a3d353c6056067fb7ef555d. Do you use the latest jOOQ version?

Comment: Version 3.2.0.  I'll update to 3.3.1.  Didn't realize how far behind I was.

Comment: Updated to 3.3.1.  Still experiencing problem.  I'll try to package it up as a separate project and post it on Github tomorrow (3/11).  Thanks for your help Lukas.

Comment: I thought so, because your code was generated with 3.0.0. Thanks for posting it to Github tomorrow.

Comment: Uploaded issue to github.  https://github.com/benjaminabbitt/potentialJooqBugCustomTypesMockJDBC

Comment: Lukas -- Anything else I can do to help get this resolved?

Comment: Apart from finding (fixing) the exact issue :-) Not right now, thanks. I'll keep you posted. I've been after some other issues...

Comment: Hi  @Lukas Eder , I'm using Jooq 3.9.0 on a new project and I'm getting this exact error. I can't see anywhere in this post if it has been fixed or I need to configure it another way. My domain classes are being generated perfectly with LocalDate instead of java.sql.Date with my Gradle build. Do I somehow need to inject my LocalDateConverter info the MockDataProvider of the DSLContext ?

Comment: @Nos: Are you sure this is the exact same error? After all, this question was asked 3 years ago... There might be other errors producing similar stack traces. I'd prefer answering an actual question (with some more info) than reviving this one here

Comment: @LukasEder, I'll create a test case for this and send it through somehow.

Comment: @Nos: Thank you very much

Comment: For the record, I've created a [bug report](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5771)

Comment: @LukasEder I took the patched version of the org.jooq.tools.jdbc.MockResultSet from the GitHub issue/commit (mentioned in the comment above) and put it in my class path. My unit tests are now running perfectly. When the 3.9.1 release is out I'll remove it again. I think you quick reactions and feedback will be a major help in extending the popularity of Jooq, so again, many thanks.

Comment: @Nos: Thanks for the feedback, and for the increased popularity :) Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

This is [bug #5771](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5771). As of jOOQ 3.9.0, `MockResultSet` doesn't use your converter to revert your user-defined type `<U>` (`DateTime`) to the JDBC/database type `<T>` (`Timestamp`) prior to exposing it through the JDBC API. Without using your converter, jOOQ doesn't know how to perform this conversion, hence the exception.

#### The correct behaviour should be:

- You create a result using `<U>` (`DateTime`) values.
- jOOQ's `MockResultSet` uses your converter to convert `<U>` to `<T>` (`Timestamp`) prior to passing that value through the JDBC API
- jOOQ's `ResultQuery` fetches `<T>` from the JDBC API
- jOOQ uses your converter to convert `<T>` back to `<U>` again

#### Workaround:

For the time being, you shouldn't put any user-defined types in your `MockResult`, but use the JDBC `Timestamp` type only (and no generated columns that refer to your user-defined type)